# One user input three different output in python, code does not work

Tags: python-2.7, fibonacci, factorial

In my homework a user is supposed to enter a number and display factorial,Fibonacci series and all cubed numbers up to the number entered by the user in Python, cannot figure out where is the problem

```
#!/Python27/python
def factorial( n ):
  if n <1:   # base case
    return 1
  else:
   return n * factorial( n - 1 )  

# recursive call
def fact(n):
  for i in range(1, n+1 ):
    print "%d" % ( factorial( i ) )

# write Fibonacci series up to n
def fib(n):    
a, b = 0, 1
while b < n:
  print b
  a, b = b, a+b

def cube(n): return n*n*n
def cubes(n):
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    print "%d" % (cube(i))

def main():
  nr = int(input("Enter a number: ")
  factorial(nr)         
  fact(nr)
  cubes(nr)

main()
```

Comment: You don't need to do `int(input())` in Python2.x

Comment: You can use `n**3` instead of `n*n*n`

Comment: so what's going wrong? Error? output? if so, what is the output?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to call the three functions from main, it gives me an error at factorial(nr) in the main function: it says invalid syntax.

Comment: `int(input("Enter a number: ")` You are missing a final `)`.

Comment: @user2254720 You should probably accept Smac89's answer & close the question now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises from you not having enough brackets:

```
def main():
  nr = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  ...
```

You forgot the closing bracket for `int()`

To display the output in a table, I would to return a list from each function then in main do something like:

```
import itertools
print "Factorial up to {n}\tFibonacci of 1 to {n}\tCubes of 1 to {n}".format(n = nr)
print '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, seq)) for seq in itertools.izip_longest(factorial(nr), fib(nr), cubes(nr), fillvalue=''))
```

Now if each of the functions (respectively) returned the following lists:

```
>>> factorial(nr)=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> fib(nr)=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> cubes(nr)=> [7, 453, 23, 676]
```

Using the above method will yield output like this:

```
Factorial up to -inf    Fibonacci of 1 to -inf  Cubes of 1 to -inf
1   3   7
2   4   453
3   5   23
4   6   676
    7
```

It doesn't quite look like a table, but if you stuff more tab characters into the output, you should get something looking closer to table format

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil but casting to int ensures that an intuitive error is thrown on that line if the user doesn't enter an int.